# Java Code Simple Math

Tags: java, math

I am stuck on the solution for code 3 below.  I need to insert a simple math problem and I cannot for the life figure this out after going over my book and sample video from class.  I would like the program to ask the question, "What is the answer to 8 raised to the power of 2"  with the answer "64".  Anyone willing to help me out?  I can come up with my other two questions if someone can just get me started!  Thank you very much!!  Kim

```
import java.util.Scanner;  //allows for input

public class ASG03 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //allows for input

        //Step 1 - Declare and initialize variables
        String candidateName = "";
        String responseE = "";

        int option = 0;
        double score = 0;


        if (score <=85)
            responseE = "Definite";
        else if (score <=70)
            responseE = "Likely";
        else if (score <=60)
            responseE = "Maybe";
        else
            responseE = "No";

        String responseI = "";

        if (score <=85)
            responseI = "Yes";
        else if (score <=70)
            responseI = "Yes";
        else if (score <=60)
            responseI = "Yes";
        else
            responseI = "No";

        //Step 2 -  Process input

        System.out.println("Enter candidate name: ");
        candidateName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter score 0 -100: ");
        score = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println();



        System.out.println("Enter 1 to set employment category ");
        System.out.println("Enter 2 to set interview possibility ");
        System.out.println("Enter 3 to view a sample test question ");
        System.out.println("Enter option now -> ");
        option = input.nextInt();





        //Step 3 and 4 - Process calculations and output
        switch(option)
        {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("You are now setting the employment category...");
            //can use nested if else
            System.out.println("Employment category =  " + responseE);

            break;


        case 2:
            System.out.println("You are now setting the interview possibilities...");
            System.out.println("Interview possibilites = " + responseI);



            break;

        case 3:
            System.out.println("You are now viewing a sample test question...");
            //use random and power from Math library


        default:


        }//end of switch

    }//end of main

}//end of class
```

Answer (score 2):

When you run your program, in the `main` you'll have that `responseE` will always be set to *"Definite"*. Because:

Look at the flow of your code:

```
double score = 0;
if (score <=85)
  responseE = "Definite";
else if (score <=70)
...
...
```

the first `if` is always satisfied, so it'll always be executed.

Furthermore, even when you'll evaluate `responseE` after you read the score, you need to consider again how you write your conditions.. note that if `score <= 85` then `score <= 70`....

You should have something like this:

Before the **switch**:

```
responseE = getResponse(score);
```

And here is the method `getResponse`:

```
private static String getResponse(double score) {
  if (score <=85 && score >70)
    return "Definite";
  else if (score <=70 && score > 60)
    return "Likely";
  else if (score <=60 && score > 40) //For example..
    return "Maybe";
  return "No";
}
```

The same for the other fields you want to evaluate **after** you read the input.

Comment: In short, you are determining the response based on the score _before you read the score_

Answer (score 0):

I need a little more information before I can give you an answer. It looks like the code wants a random number generator, however in your question you asked for 8^2, or 8*8. Which would you like? I ask because random number generation is a lot different than hard coding number variables

Comment: Thank you all for the corrections.  New class for me and I am NOT catching on quickly.  IrishWhiskey (Random number)  I think?!  It's suppose to ask the question and tell the user if the answer is correct or incorrect...?